# Struct name used with round brackets and operator()

Tags: c++

I was using some numerical integration package in BOOST (See code below).
Anyone can explain the meaning of:

```
double operator()(double x) {return x/std::log(x);}
```

What is this "operator()(double x)"??

```
quadrature::adaptive()(f(), 0., 1., answer, error_estimate);
```

What is "f()" here?

---

```
#include <boost/numeric/quadrature/adaptive.hpp>
#include <boost/numeric/quadrature/kronrodgauss.hpp>
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>

namespace quadrature=boost::numeric::quadrature;

struct f
{
  double operator()(double x) const { return x/std::log(x); }
};


int main()
{
  double answer, error_estimate;
  // integrate x/log(x) on [0,1]
  quadrature::adaptive()(f(), 0., 1., answer, error_estimate);

  std::cout << "integtral(x/log(x)) on [0,1] is " << answer
            << " with error estimate " << error_estimate
            << std::endl;

  return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Comment: `operator()(double x)` is simply making a function object of f so you can pass a double to it like so: `f()(0.12345);`

Comment: `f` is a `struct` (or a `class`, if you want to change it) acting like a function.

Comment: It's a `functor`, that is, a function object. Usually used when you want to pass something around that emulates a function which can also store state. There's pretty much no reason for it here, however, it could easily be just a function.

Comment: @chris That's what the additional () is there for:)

Comment: @Troy, My bad, I mistook your syntax for something else.

Answer (score 2):

`f` is a functor, i.e. a class (or struct, in this case) that defines an `operator()`. This means that instances of this class can be used as if they were functions:

```
f myinstance;
myinstance(2.3);
```

The `operator()` defines the signature and behaviour of `f` instances when used as functions, i.e. it provides the definition of the actual function that is executed when `myinstance` is applied to arguments.

The `f()` means: create a anonymous instance of `f`, using the default constructor. I.e. it works like `f myinstance` in my example above, except that the instance created doesn't have a name.

As you can see, the instance of `f` is passed as argument to the `adaptive` call. Internally, this instance is then applied as a function to various objects. In other words, the entire mechanism enables you to define a function (in the form of a functor like `f`) and pass it along as an argument.

Answer (score 1):

`operator()` is the C++ function call operator. it means that you can apply an argument parenthesis to an object of the class, and then that operator is called.

regarding the `f()`, presumably that's an instantiation of the `struct f` that you show below.

you need a c++ textbook